# match exactly a word starting with $( or special character)contained in a string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, string

how do i exactly match a word like `$abc` from a string `"this is $$abc abc$abc $abc abc_$abc_ing";`

Comment: What is the output expected ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
(\$[a-z]+)
```

Explanation:

```
(        : Start of group
  \$     : A literal $. Since $ is a metacharacter we escape it.
  [a-z]+ : one or more letters that is a word. You can use the modifier i 
           to match uppercase letters aswell.
)        : End of grouping
```

Comment: @yb007 '\' escapes any special character

Comment: $target_str= 'this is $$abc abc$abc $abc abc_$abc_ing';   $target_str =~ s/(\$abc)/replaced/g;
print $target_str; **Current Output** this is $replaced abcreplaced replaced abc_replaced_ing  **Expected Output** this is $$abc abc$abc replaced abc_$abc_ing

Comment: Try using `$target_str =~ s/(?<= )(\$abc)(?= )/replaced/g;`

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply **it works fine** _A brief explanation of the latest regex used would be highly appreciable_ thanks in advance!!